# How do I switch from an old version of ADK to new version permanently in Windows 2012 R2 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, dism, wim, adk

Methods attempted:

1. Edited the environment variable PATH and kept path of ADK "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\dism.exe" in the front
2. Installed and Re-installed 10.0.19041.1 version in server (verified in control panel)
3. Edited PATH using Powershell

   $env:path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM"
   import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM"

I want to switch to the new version in order to service a WIM file

Comment: What are you doing that doesn't work correctly after all you have done?

Comment: how did you change the path environmental variable in step 1? If you use set in a command prompt, note that you also need to use setx to make it a permanent change.

Comment: also, if you change the parameter of path in the command prompt, does it work as expected directly after that change? If not, then changing the path is not the solution to your underlying problem.